# How to parse through many hashes using foreach?

Tags: perl

```
foreach my %hash (%myhash1,%myhash2,%myhash3)
{
   while (($keys,$$value) = each %hash)
   {
      #use key and value...
   }
}
```

Why doesn't this work :

it says synta error on foreach line.
Pls tell me why is it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong because you seem to think that this allows you to access each hash as a separate construct, whereas what you are in fact doing is, besides a syntax error, accessing the hashes as a mixed-together new list. For example:

```
my %hash1 = qw(foo 1 bar 1);
my %hash2 = qw(abc 1 def 1);

for (%hash1, %hash2)  # this list is now qw(foo 1 bar 1 abc 1 def 1)
```

When you place a hash (or array) in a list context statement, they are expanded into their elements, and their integrity is not preserved. Some built-in functions do allow this behaviour, but normal Perl code does not.

You also cannot assign a hash as the `for` iterator variable, that can only ever be a scalar value. What you can do is this:

```
for my $hash (\%myhash1, \%myhash2, \%myhash3) {
    while (my ($key, $value) = each %$hash) {
        ...
```

Which is to say, you create a list of hash references and iterate over them. Note that you cannot tell the difference between the hashes with this approach.

Note also that I use `my $hash` because this variable must be a scalar.

Comment: Thank you. Thanks a lot. I have understood the whole concept of hashes now.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be like:

```
my $hash1 = {'a'=>1};
my $hash2 = {'b'=>1};

my @arr2 = ($hash1, $hash2);

foreach $hash (@arr2)
{
                while(($key, $value) = each %$hash)
                {
                                print $key, $value;
                }
}
```

you need to reference and then dereference the hash.

Comment: You are correct that you would need to use a hash ref. It doesn't necessary need to start out as an anonymous hash ref though (`$hash={}`). You would only need to create a reference to the hash `$hash_ref = \%hash`